# Is it possible to add values via Plugin.xml to Config.xml?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am required to add this for Universal Link capabilities inside config.xml:

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="example.com">
        <path url="/some/path" />
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

Since I am not able to modify config.xml (auto-generated project and app), I only have chance to change on [plugin](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin) source code level.

Can anyone advise me how to do so?

Comment: I have searched thoroughly but still unable to find any way to do it

Comment: Read the documentation properly. Everything is written there in details : https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin#cordova-config-preferences

Comment: "Cordova uses config.xml" --> I am not able to change `config.xml` because I use platform to auto gen project and app

Comment: `I am not able to change config.xml`. Your problem is you're unable to configure the configuration file :-@